# How to deploy a Ruby app - not ROR?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am very new to `ruby` and I wonder, **Is it possible to have my ruby script deployed on a server?**
Or I should have to use Rails?

As I can understood that Rails is not part of the core `Ruby` lang, and `Ruby` have `server` functionality even without Rails. (as in Java, PHP, etc..)

**EDIT**:

I have a `Ruby script` - acts as a cmd-line passed program - and I want to deploy it to an external (or even internal) server the way `CGI` scripts/programs used to do.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The fact that Ruby has a Web server in its Standard Library has no relation with any deployment process.

Comment: And I am not talking about deployment process, I just want to have my cmd-line based script to be converted to running service. (a way CGI is working)

Comment: -1er's Please give me a reasone to -1 my question??

Comment: I suspect you're getting downvoted because your question isn't very clear. You don't seem to understand the technologies, and, though it might seem harsh, Stack Overflow isn't the place to gain that knowledge, as it'll take a lot more space than a single answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy any Ruby application, not just Rails apps obviously. Take a look at [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano).

Deployment and serving are two different things however. If you're looking for Ruby HTTP servers look at Unicorn, Thin, WEBrick, Puma.

If you want a fully-fledged solution try [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) which handles both the *deployment* and *web serving* parts.

Comment: Cannot find more simpler tool? as it says about itself `A remote server automation and deployment tool written in Ruby.` I just want a `ruby server/container`

Comment: Popular ruby servers: Unicorn, Thin, WEBrick, Puma

Comment: Easiest way to deploy a Ruby/Rack application if you aren't familiar with deployments or sysadmin is to use Heroku. Otherwise you probably shouldn't be messing with it until Capistrano, Rack, Unicorn, and Thin have meaning in your life.

Comment: I used `Heroku` with `sinatra`

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools to deploy Ruby projects, but you can do it pretty much manually.

I also found it very hard to find an easy-to-go solution and I think this is a very annoying gap in RoR framework.

I've been working in a solution to deploy a project to a server using Git, like the Heroku toolbelt (google it, is a really nice tool). The main concept is: you use Git to push your project and the server does everything else! Here you can see my project: https://github.com/sentient06/RDH/.

But please, don't focus on that. Instead, read the way I came to all information in the wiki: https://github.com/sentient06/RDH/wiki.

It is a bit outdated, but I can summarize here to you:

First, setup your server. This is the most boring part, you must setup all configuration, security measures, remote access, etc, etc.

If you don't have a server, you can hire one specially for RoR applications. There are a few good out there and each has a different deployment workflow. But supposing you decide o setup yourself:

I suggest you have any Linux or Unix system, server version. Then install Ruby Version Manager, then Ruby and then Rails. Then install a server application. I suggest Thin, but lots of people use Unicorn or Apache or other servers. Dig a little bit on the internet, find an easy to use solution. If you do not use Apache, though, you will need a "reverse proxy" too, so you can redirect all requests on ports 80, 8080, etc, to your applications. I suggest Nginx (I don't like Apache, I think is too overkill).

Now, everything done, the deploy process **can** be done more or less like this:

1 - Commit everything in a way your files are updated in the server;

2 - In the server, `cd` to the directory of your application and execute these commands:

```
$ bundle package
$ bundle install --deployment
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
$ rake assets:precompile
```

3 - Restart the server and, if necessary, the reverse proxy.

Dig on the internet to understand each command. These will pretty much force your application into production mode, reduce the space used by your javascript and CSS, migrate your production database and install the bundles. Production RoR is not so different from development RoR, it is just more compact and faster.

I do hope these informations are useful.

Good luck!

**Update**:

I forgot to mention, check `ruby-toolbox`, it has some really useful statistics and information on how often Rails technologies are being updated. They have many categories, this one is on deployment automation, give it a look: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/deployment_automation.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for this information, however I found `Heroku` -with `sinatra` much simpler.

Comment: I like `Heroku` a lot, it is really nice. I also used `Rails Playgroung`, is not bad, but the use `Apache` and `Passenger` (I don't like Passenger). I forgot to mention, check `ruby-toolbox`, it has some really useful statistics and information on how often Rails technologies are being updated. They have many categories, this one is on deployment automation, give it a look: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/deployment_automation. I'll put the link in the answer too. Cheers!